# OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_parse_stoc_server_name', 'bad extension')] using request.get

Tags: ssl, openssl, python-requests

import requests

url = 'https://v11.com:8080'

res = requests.get(url, verify = 'ca.arraynetca.cert.pem')

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dbansal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 472, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\dbansal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1716, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\Users\dbansal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1456, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\Users\dbansal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_parse_stoc_server_name', 'bad extension')]

"""

ssl Server is running with TLSv1:TLSv11:TLSv12:TLSv13.

through openssl s_client -connect ssl handshake is working fine using tls1_2 protocol.

"""

Comment: That error occurs if the server responds with an invalid SNI extension in the TLS ServerHello. In other words it appears to be a TLS protocol violation. Can you get a wireshark packet trace of a failing connection? What version of OpenSSL are you using? Do you know what the server is?

Comment: Thanks Matt, SNI extension in server hello was incorrect.OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019.

Comment: This should never happen and indicates a problem on the server side.

Comment: Yes, its a bug with my server software.

Comment: Hi Matt , could please guide me to learn about how to troubleshoot this exception thrown in request module. As i am testing software where TLS1.3 support we are adding . Regression script failed today with   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')")).

Comment: WSAECONNRESET means the remote peer abruptly closed the connection. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2